# How to change date format into the comma separated column?

Tags: mysql

I have comma separated value like **2018-06-20 01:12:53,2018-06-20 01:14:11** 
But the problem is I need date and time format like **day-month-Year H:i** when I use `DATE_FORMAT(t1.pickup_date_time, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i")`
it could not run because the column(**pickup_date_time**) has comma separated value. 
Your help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Take some time to think about restructuring your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUBSTRING_INDEX first to split the column on the comma. Then use STR_TO_DATE to reformat the date.   If you have issue with the actual code, let me know.